# Closure Library with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-closure-library

Google's Closure Library looks like it has a lot of great features, but I'm not seeing any examples of it used with ASP.NET sites. I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience using the two together and what parts. Is is a good or bad experience?

EDIT:
To clarify, I'm asking about Closure Library and not Closure Compiler or Closure Templates. For example, if I use the calendar control from Closure Library, it seems to decorate a text box so that text might have to be converted to a DateTime on post back. Whereas other ASP.NET controls will expose a SelectedDate property, for example. There are probably some cases where this incomplete integration is annoying, and probably some cases where the controls in the Library provide features that are compelling enough that it is worth dealing with any quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Closure Library is platform agnostic. It is as useful with
ASP.NET as it is with any other platform.

Closure Templates (another member of the Closure Tools family),
does have a server-side component that's limited to
Java. However, that does not limit the utility of Closure Library
in any way.

For any production application using Closure Library, you will
need to compile your code using Closure Compiler. To do this
locally, you will need to install both Python and Java. Neither
of these are needed in your deployment environment, though.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft providing their own JavaScript minifier ( http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/34488 ) and embracing and supporting JQuery (+ intellisense and documentation) in Visual Studio I am not surprised ASP.NET folks are skipping Google's Closure.